# Angular JS - Scope Watch Not Updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I might be using this wrong, but I have a function that watches a variable and when that variable is changed from the view, the function runs.. but when a sibling function changes that variable the watch doesn't run. Am I coding something wrong?

```
scope.$watch (settings.number, function(val){
    alert('test');
})
scope.exampleObj = {
    exampleFunc : function(){
        settings.number += 5;
    }
};
```

so when I call scope.exampleObj.exampleFunc(); shouldn't scope watch get called?

Comment: I think changes within children do not trigger the change. Can you try watching on number itself, and updating the number rather than enclosing in parent object. Not sure, but I had same issue on an older version of angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace string to a function or use $watchCollection, like this:

**Using var:**

```
angular.module('TestApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
        // Object
        var settings = {
            number: 1,
            foobar: 'Hello World'
        };

        $scope.$watch(function(){ return settings.number; }, function(newValue, oldValue){
            console.log('New value detected in settins.number');
        });

        $scope.$watchCollection(function(){ return settings; }, function(newValue, oldValue){
            console.log('New value detected in settings');
        });
    });
```

**Using $scope:**

```
angular.module('TestApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
        // Object
        $scope.settings = {
            number: 1,
            foobar: 'Hello World'
        };

        $scope.$watch('settings.number', function(newValue, oldValue){
            console.log('New value detected in $scope.settings.number');
        });
    });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Chofoteddy/2SNFG/

***Note**: $watchCollection that is available in AngularJS version 1.1.x and above. It can be really useful if you need to watch multiple values in a array or multiple properties in a object.

Answer (score 1):

The watcher expects the name(ie. string) of a property of inside the scope, not the object itself.

```
scope.$watch ('settings.number', function(newval,oldval){
   alert('test');
});
  scope.exampleObj = {
  exampleFunc : function(){
      scope.settings.number += 5;
  }
};
```

I'm assuming the somewhere you declare `scope.settings.number` first, and that you meant to set `scope.settings.number` not `settings.number` as you can only watch variables which are properties of the angular `scope`.

Though you may be doing the right thing with just `settings.number += 5;`, I may just be tired.

Comment: @marck, why thank you kind sir for the fiddle :). I am assuming the problem was one of not watching a `$scope` variable.

Comment: @marck the variable is declared higher up, turns out the issue wasn't with this part.. It works unless I have the number updated with a time interval.

Comment: @pashOCONNOR, does the timer interval use the `$scope.apply` function? reading material: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `objectEquality` to true . so you can compare for object equality using angular.equals instead of comparing for reference equality.

for more infos visit [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)

```
scope.$watch (settings.number, function(val){
    alert('test');
},true)
scope.exampleObj = {
    exampleFunc : function(){
        settings.number += 5;
    }
};
```