# Why aren't events from within my angular controller triggering more than once?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I'm trying to get angulartics set up in a component that is being used to display errors/important info to users in a banner.  However, I'm running into an issue where it seems like the values inside of the controller aren't updating or running when expected despite the banners functioning as expected.

What is happening: `ctrl.isBannerVisible` is defined as true on the test page load, triggering the banner, but the value doesn't update when toggling visibility despite the banner actually disappearing and re-appearing.  'Banner is visible' only ever prints once in console despite being toggled on and off multiple times.

What is expected: 'Banner is visible' should be printed in the console each time `ctrl.isBannerVisible` is evaluated to true.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Here is the related code below:

core.component.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    /** @ngInject */
    function bannerCtrl($scope, $analytics) {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.showCloseIcon = false;

        if (angular.isDefined(ctrl.hasCloseIcon)) {
            ctrl.showCloseIcon = true;
        }

        ctrl.bannerStyle = ctrl.bannerStyle || 'alert';

        ctrl.$onDestroy = function () {
            if (ctrl.onClosed) {
                ctrl.onClosed();
            }
        }

        $scope.$watch('isBannerVisible',
            function(previousValue, currentValue) {
                if(currentValue){
                    console.log('Banner is visible');
                }
            }
        );

        ctrl.onCloseClicked = function() {
            ctrl.isBannerVisible = false;
            if (ctrl.onClosed) {
                ctrl.onClosed();
            }
        }
    }

    var BannerComponent = {
        templateUrl: 'components/core/banner.tpl.html'
        , transclude: true
        , controller: bannerCtrl
        , bindings: {
            // Use 'has-close-icon' attribute (no values necessary) to display the close icon.
            iconName: '@?'
            , hasCloseIcon: '@?'
            , bannerStyle: '@?'
            , isBannerVisible: '='
            , onClosed: '&?'
        }
    };

    angular.module('mi.banner.core').component('miBanner', BannerComponent);

    BannerComponent.$inject = [
        '$scope', '$analytics'
    ];
}());
```

template:

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="start center">
    <div flex="100" ng-class="'mi-uam-banner--' + $ctrl.bannerStyle" ng-if="$ctrl.isBannerVisible">
        <div flex="none" class="mi-icat-icon">
            <div class="{{$ctrl.iconName}}"></div>
        </div>
        <div flex="grow" class="mi-icat-content" ng-transclude></div>
        <div layout layout-align="center center" flex="none" class="mi-icat-action" ng-if="$ctrl.showCloseIcon">
            <a class="mi-icon-action-close" ng-click="$ctrl.onCloseClicked()"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sample implementation:

```
<button id="toggleBannerVisibility" ng-click="main.toggleBannerVisibility()">Toggle banner visibility</button>
<mi-banner banner-style="global" icon-name="mi-icon-add-filled-circle" has-close-icon is-banner-visible="main.isBannerVisible">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
    <p>
        <a id="asdf" href="" ng-click="main.wow()">RETRY</a>
    </p>
</mi-banner>
```

test controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    /** @ngInject */
    function MainController() {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.isBannerVisible = true;
        ctrl.destroyed = false;

        function toggleBannerVisibility() {
            ctrl.isBannerVisible = !ctrl.isBannerVisible;
        }

        function wow() {
            window.alert('WOW!');
        }

        ctrl.wow = wow;
        ctrl.toggleBannerVisibility = toggleBannerVisibility;
    }

    angular
      .module('mi.banner.test-page')
      .controller('MainController', MainController);
}());
```

Note: I have removed the $analytics event tracking code as it isn't actually necessary for the issue I'm facing.

Comment: Looking at your code (and not having used angular in quite some time) it looks to me as if your bannerCtrl function is only executed once when you wire up the controller. It runs through the if block and so on as you'd expect giving you the console output. When you toggle the banner visibility, you're not executing the entire controller again, rather you're changing the bound boolean value in the controller.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense.

Comment: Daniel Lane is right, if you want it to be called each time your item changes, you need to use $scope.$watch('isBannerVisible', function (){
            console.log('Banner is visible');
        });

Comment: @Groben. `$scope.$watch('isBannerVisible', function (){ console.log('Banner is visible'); });` only tells you if `isBannerVisible` changed from `true` to `false`. You need to only `log to console` if its true. check my answer below:

Comment: @raneshu to be fair, neither Groben nor your solution works for me right now.  I implemented both but at most I get 'Banner is visible' printed on load and nothing else (when using Groben's suggestion).

Comment: @raneshu I know, it was just to give him the idea. No need to post an answer for this kind of question

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$watch`, for that, you need to inject `$scope`.

```
MainController.$inject['$scope'];

function MainController($scope){
   $scope.$watch('isBannerVisible', function(){
       //logic goes here
   });
}
```

Example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/51bsbzL0/246/)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, while the other answers were close in what I was looking for, because I'm using only `controller` level variables, `$scope` doesn't have `$watch` access to `isBannerVisible`.  I have to use:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return ctrl.isBannerVisible },
            function(currentValue, previousValue) {
                if(currentValue){
                    console.log('Banner is visible');
                }
            }
        );
```

Link to answer that showed me this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23231762/2925985

Comment: Well it's actively working on my machine sooooo...YUP!

Comment: yeah, but no need to use a function to " { return ctrl.isBannerVisible }"

Comment: It doesn't work if I just use a string value...which makes sense because it arguably shouldn't from that context.  I'll try just `ctrl.isBannerVisible`, if that works, and you revert your answer to reflect that, yours will be correct.

Comment: Just did, and it didn't work.  Only works with that `function`.

Comment: Ok my bad then, I don't know why the fiddle works thou =/

Comment: I'm not sure either, I'm guessing it has to do with either the version of angular or how our scopes are being defined.  Either way, thank you for helping!